# "Located", "situated" or nothing

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

> The stadium is **situated** in London.
>
> The stadium is **located** in London.
>
> The stadium is **in** London.

Could anyone please tell me the difference?

Which one is preferred in **spoken English?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They all mean the same; 'located' and 'situated' are more formal.

Answer (score -1):

"Situated" and "located", like all words in English, have slightly different meanings, in some contexts, but in your example I can't see even a minor difference between your three choices. For that reason alone, the last (shortest) one is most likely to be used in both written and spoken English, though the first two (longer) options are more likely to occur in written English than spoken out loud.